# TYPO3 breaks urls without WWW

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, typo3, realurl

The problem is that when I want to access my website like **www.example.com/my/subpage** all works great but when I try to access my website like this (without WWW) **example.com/my/subpage** TYPO3 breaks it down and redirect it to **www.example.com/index.php/subpage**.

The redirect from non WWW to WWW is correct but why does it destroy my url? Here is the .htaccess redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

For the "nice" urls I use the realURL extension. Any ideas?

Edit (more htaccess):

```
RewriteRule ^(typo3|t3lib|tslib|fileadmin|typo3conf|typo3temp|uploads|showpic\.php|favicon\.ico)/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^typo3$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^typo3/.*$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Comment: Do you have other rules in this .htaccess also?

Comment: Yes but I think nothing special. Added it to my question above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep your 301 rules before other internal rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^(typo3|t3lib|tslib|fileadmin|typo3conf|typo3temp|uploads|showpic\.php|favicon\.ico)/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^typo3(/.*)?$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Also test this in a new browser to avoid browser caching issues.