# I can't find htaccess in typo3

Tags: .htaccess, typo3

I am using Typo3 4.5., and am running into the problem which appears to be solved here: [TYPO3 breaks urls without WWW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360834/typo3-breaks-urls-without-www)  ...  (website redirects to index without WWW)

The answer recommended there involves editing the htaccess file.

My problem is I cannot find this file anywhere. I am not experienced with Typo3, how can I safely edit this document?

I have gone into my filelist and found an htaccess file at [fileadmin/]: *temp*/ but I cannot edit this document. Clicking on it gives me an error 403 in a new window. In german nonetheless.

Comment: Probably you've a reason to use version 4.5. Nevertheless it can't be stressed enough that this version shouldn't be used for production anymore as it has no support anymore and it has to be assumed that it includes many security issues. I experienced some issues already long time ago.

Answer (score 5):

Even the question is related to a very old TYPO3 version I want to answer here for the current version 9.5 where several `.htaccess` files are saved in the folder

```
typo3/sysext/install/Resources/Private/FolderStructureTemplateFiles/
```

These are the files in that folder:

> **fileadmin-temp-htaccess**
>   fileadmin-temp-index.html
>   **fileadmin-user_upload-temp-importexport-htaccess**
>   **root-htaccess**
>   root-web-config
>   **typo3temp-var-htaccess**

All files with `htaccess` at the end (above bold text) should be used according to the filename, copied in the corresponding directory and each copy then renamed to `.htaccess`.

The other files should be used too according to name and content.

It has to be considered that `.htaccess`-files perhaps are not exchangeable always between TYPO3 versions; I never had problems with it during many updates but it should always be checked.

Answer (score 3):

The .htaccess file is a hidden file and is located in the document root of your website. This file can't be edited from inside of TYPO3, you need direct access to the webserver (ssh, sftp, ...)

Answer (score 2):

If you installed TYPO3 from the "dummy package", it should have a "_.htaccess" file in the root that must be renamed. As the previous answer by @M Klein told you, you must rename or edit it by direct access to your server.

Another possibility is that the file has been accidentally removed; in this case you could download the ["dummy package"](https://sourceforge.net/projects/typo3/files/TYPO3%20Source%20and%20Dummy/) (select your TYPO3 version) and pick a new one from there.